# Htaccess redirect URL to Alias

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite Rule: 
`RewriteRule abc\.html$ index.php?page=1 [L]`

If a user attempts to open index.php?page=1 i would like to redirect him with a 301 to abc.html. I've tried the following:
`RewriteRule index\.php\?page=1$ abc.html [R=301,L]`

It doesn't work. Is there a solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?page=1(&|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /abc.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=1/?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /abc.html? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: This will cause a rewrite loop because of the other rule